# Assign a user a unique user ID who submits to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cookies, session-cookies

I have a site where someone posts data to a mysql table , then the data is displayed to the public on a secondary page.

What I need is each time someone submits data to mysql table, I want the user to receive a unique ID, and the table row to be linked to the user specifically.

**Reason why:** Eventually, I intend to have users be able to delete/update their own submissions that are shown publicly. They should be able to only delete their OWN info if they have the same ID as the info in the mysql table.

**Task:**

Please let me know if this flow of thought is correct, and how to start assigning ID's to users, and to the table row itself.

Thanks!

Comment: so have you written any code or are you just trying to come up with ideas?

Comment: Please offer an idea for critique, or a couple of alternative ideas, and ask which one is better and reasons why.

Comment: I have the code written,  I was trying to find the best way to link the user to the submitted data so they can delete or edit the table row. Then the session would expire after 30 min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal procedure is simple: When creating a new user, use the ID that results from your `INT AUTO_INCREMENT` column by checking `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

If you want, push this value into the `$_SESSION` to persist it for subsequent requests.

Comment: This seems to be the best way, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the session_id() to create a special identificator for a user.

Comment: What if they sign up twice with the same session identifier?

Comment: Just don't allow them to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerious ways:

- IP
- set cookie on client-side in order to reuse it

Answer (score 0):

Tadman is right http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html

This is a Session Based way to get the value of an autoincremented field, after insert...

So whatever the user does as long as you insert und get insert id on the same session you are safe :-)